# Problems with grid system (Bootstrap) for navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I would like to provide a **navigation bar** for a website, which can be expanded with the "*Show more*" button, so that further filter options are available. The navigation bar should only contain a search field and the button - and both in just **one row**.

However, it looks like this:
[Open Image with Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ksQI.png)

The project uses **Bootstrap** and I have also played around with the **grid system** and looked at the documentation, but these attempts have *not* led to success.

I have also managed to have both components in *one* line, but this resulted in the search field being very small in width.

Here is the code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
          
          <!--<div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
          </div>--> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Show more</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h5 class="text-body-emphasis h4">Collapsed content</h5>
      <span class="text-body-secondary">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am happy about any constructive answer! :)

I would also like to know if there are better (preferably free) alternatives to Bootstrap? Thanks for any tips!

See above, everything is described there